# Rank date column based on dates in another table date column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, partition-by

I have the following tables

```
df_obs.show()
```

| Item No | Date_Observed |
| --- | --- |
| Item 1 | 2021-09-20 |
| Item 1 | 2022-12-05 |
| Item 2 | 2022-10-27 |
| Item 1 | 2022-09-20 |
| Item 2 | 2023-02-20 |
| Item 2 | 2023-03-20 |
| Item 1 | 2023-01-20 |

```
df_purchase.withColumn("rank", dense_rank().over(Window.partitionBy("ITEM_No").orderBy(asc("Date_Purchase")))).show()
```

| Item_No | Date_Purchase | rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item 1 | 2021-08-21 | 1 |
| Item 1 | 2022-02-23 | 2 |
| Item 1 | 2022-12-29 | 3 |
| Item 2 | 2022-09-20 | 1 |
| Item 2 | 2023-01-20 | 2 |

I want to rank df_obs Date_Observed column based on rank in df_purchase
That is Date_Observed comes between which date range

**Needed Output**

| Item No | Date_Observed | rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item 1 | 2021-09-20 | 1 |
| Item 1 | 2022-12-05 | 2 |
| Item 2 | 2022-10-27 | 1 |
| Item 1 | 2022-09-20 | 2 |
| Item 2 | 2023-02-20 | 2 |
| Item 2 | 2023-03-20 | 2 |
| Item 1 | 2023-01-15 | 3 |

Example: row 2 in df_obs get rank 2 as Date_Observed (2022-12-05) comes between 2022-02-23 (rank 2) and 2022-12-29(rank3) in df_purchase table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the join condition to match the rows having same item number but the observed date in left datafrmae must be greater than the purchase date in the right then join the dataframes on this condition then group and aggregate rank with max

```
cond = (df_obs['Item No'] == df_purchase['Item_No']) & \
       (df_obs['Date_Observed'] >= df_purchase['Date_Purchase'])


result = (
    df_obs
    .join(df_purchase, on=cond, how='left')
    .groupBy(*df_obs.columns)
    .agg(F.max('rank').alias('rank'))
)
```

Result

```
+-------+-------------+----+
|Item No|Date_Observed|rank|
+-------+-------------+----+
| Item 1|   2021-09-20|   1|
| Item 1|   2022-12-05|   2|
| Item 2|   2022-10-27|   1|
| Item 1|   2022-09-20|   2|
| Item 2|   2023-02-20|   2|
| Item 2|   2023-03-20|   2|
| Item 1|   2023-01-20|   3|
+-------+-------------+----+
```